# What is the point of sub and superscripts in metric tensor

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, notation

I am new to QFT and have to catch up with some things that I did not learn from my SR courses. I am learning about the tensor notation, in particular the metric tensor, $$g_{\nu\mu}=g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$
However, I don't understand the point of the subscripts, as the content of the matrix seems to be independent of both $\mu$ and $\nu$. So what do those sub indexes indicate?

Comment: Unfortunately you've chosen the least interesting tensor to see what happens when you manipulate indices as the Minkowski metric is its own inverse (and is diagonal), so permuting the indices around doesn't do much to it.

Comment: Can you show an example where the `content of the matrix is dependent on the indices`?

Comment: I don't understand much of the matter, so I don't know an example of it. But from what I do understand, the sub or superscripts should be an indicator of dimension or some similar property. However, in the metric tensor the dimension seems to be fixed, so I don't understand why the subscripts are needed, if (i think that) they don't contribute any information

Comment: There's a difference between how mathematicians treat notation and how physicists treat notation. You're absolutely right that there is a difference between the _matrix_ $g$ and the _coefficients of the matrix_ $g_{\mu\nu}$. However, the distinction is not very relevant outside of pure mathematics, so the non-mathematician is allowed to take liberty in how he treats the notation. The reason why we include the subscripts/superscripts all the time is because they immediately give you useful info about the _rank_ of your tensor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SR, the invariant "length" of a vector is given by 
$$
ds^2= (c dt)^2-(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)
$$
and so you need to keep track of where the signs appear.  Thus, it is convenient to introduce a metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ so that, if $(cd t,dx,dy,dz)$ are components of a vector $(dx^0,dx^1,dx^2,dx^3)$ then 
$$
ds^2= dx^\mu g_{\mu\nu} dx^\nu
$$
with $g_{\mu\nu}$ as given.  Since expressions such as $g_{\mu\nu} dx^\nu$ occur quite often, one defines $dx_\mu=g_{\mu\nu} dx^\nu$ so that we can also write
$$
ds^2=dx^\mu dx_\mu\, ,
$$
where $dx_0=c dt, dx_1=-dx, dx_2=-dy, dx_3=-dz$.

The raising and lowering of indices is done with $g_{\mu\nu}$ or its inverse $g^{\mu\nu}$ (they happen to coincide in your case but might not when using non-Cartesian bases for 3-space).

Note that in ordinary Euclidean space, $\tilde g_{ij}=\hbox{diag}(1,1,1)$ and the length is just
$$d\ell^2= dx^2+dy^2+dz^2 = dx^i \tilde g_{ij}dx^j.$$  Since $\tilde g$ is just the unit matrix, there is 
no difference between $dx^i$ and $dx_i$.

In general you need a metric when the scalar product between two vectors is "non-standard".  This happens in SR because of the - signs in the $ds$ but you also need a metric if you are using non-orthogonal coordinate system.  In such system (say in the 2-d place where $\hat x$ and $\hat y$ are not orthogonal) one can write a general vector
$$
\vec V=V^x\hat x+V^y\hat y
$$
meaning you take a specific linear combo of $\hat x$ and $\hat y$ to get $\vec V$.  However,  $V^x$ and $V^y$ are not components obtained by the scalar product of $\vec V$ with $\hat x$ or $\hat y$.  Rather
$$
V_x=\vec V\cdot\hat x\, ,\qquad V_y=\vec V\cdot\hat y
$$ 
and $V_x=V^x+V^y\cos\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the angle between $\hat x$ and $\hat y$.  You can find more details on this nice geometrical distinction between components with upper and lower indices in

> James Evans, Am. J. Phys. **65**  (1997) p. 1039.

I'm including a diagram from this paper as a teaser, showing the meaning of $V^x, V^y, V_x$ and $V_y$:
[image]

In GR, metric tensors are often non-diagonal.
Finally, there is a nice discussion done in the context of SR in the (wonderful) book

> Brau, C.A., 2004. Modern problems in classical electrodynamics. Oxford univ. press

with various examples, including the electromagnetic field tensor $F^{\mu\nu}$.  The positioning of indices in this tensor is particularly important.

Answer (score 4):

Writing

$$M_{\mu \nu} = \pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}$$
is shorthand notation for

$$M_{00} = a, M_{01} = b, M_{10} = c, M_{11} = d$$

In this sense, you're right - the subscripts $\mu\nu$ don't really have any particular significance in this expression.  It would be not be unreasonable to simply write

$$\mathbf M = \pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}$$

---

However, it is of utmost importance to remember that there is a difference between a tensor $\mathbf M$ - a basis-independent geometrical object - and the *components* of that tensor $M_{\mu \nu}$ (where $\mu,\nu = 0,1,\ldots $) as expressed in a particular basis.  I personally tend to attach the indices to make it extra clear that I'm working in some basis, while any object in bold font with no indices should be understood to be basis-independent, but that's just a personal convention.

Comment: In a sense I agree with this answer and it has been chosen by the OP but at the same time there are situations when the ordering of indices matters and I really think that needs to be addressed in order to fully answer the OP's question. For instance the face that $F^{\mu \nu} = - F^{\nu \mu}$, which I think would still be helpful to mention as it shows properties like antisymmetry.

Answer (score 0):

The indices indicate the value of the matrix. For example g00 = -1, g01=0. The difference between sub and superscripts is the two different types tensors. Covariant and contravariant. You can figure out the other one by the equation gνμ(covariant)*gνμ(contravariant)=(identity-matrix)νμ

Also note that g00 should be c^2. The identity matrix is just the metric tensor except g00-> gnn is 1

Comment: Answers on this site are expected to use MathJax for all mathematics.